# Android facebook authentication

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an android application, Generally application contains a login screen, In my application there will be no log in screen, there will be a single icon e.g Facebook icon. If I press that icon it should directly login with the Facebook user name and password and it should log in to the application. Can any one give me suggestion on this?

Comment: what do you mean by "a suggestion"?

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Help me on this issue to authenticate with the face book directly

Comment: What have you tried? have you looked at the documentation and tutorials? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/

Comment: @Sukesh: I am not sure what exactly you wish to achieve. But if your requirement is to bypass the Facebook login screen, then to my knowledge, that is not an option. All authentications must pass though the FB SDK using either the SSO if the FB default app is installed or through the login dialog box if the FB App is not installed. Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Download latest Facebook SDK for android. and you can find examples in that you can achieve ur task.

Comment: @Sukesh You can check my answer for further reference on Single-Sign-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes You can do that but Only one condition is that you have to Integrate **Single-Sign-On** into your Application and also you should have **Facebook Native App** in your Mobile.

Download the Facebook book SDK from this [Link.](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

After downloading follow this [Steps](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Register your Application in Facebook Account.
Then Create Set up Login Pages as in the Steps.

Create Hash Key for enabling [Single-Sign-On](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig) using Keytool.

**Note** : If you want to start you App without providing Login details , Facebook Native App should be installed and Logged In.

Else you will asked for **Login very First time** , next time your App will Launch Automatically without asking for Login Credentials.

This also depends on Access Token so , handle it accordingly.

For more reference on [Access Token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#token)

Comment: Thanks i am following the same steps to do my application. The problem i am facing is my application is not authenticating with the face book application. in the line facebook.authorize() onFacebookError() method  is calling

Comment: no error but it is not authenticating

Comment: apart from Inernet Permission, i need to gice any other permission in android manifest file

Comment: Not needed.. You added Appid into your App?

Comment: Show ur code please. use http://www.pastie.org

Comment: http://www.pastie.org/3924396

Comment: Hi @Venky while am integrating facebook  into my android application am getting the following waring .have a look on to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729923/android-facebooksharing-integration

Answer (score 2):

hi u can try following examples
1)
http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/290-facebook-integration-in-your-android-application

2)Download latest SDK from Github
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Functionality u want is called Single- Sign on. Check more related questions